# Passing stateless widget from one screen to another screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a `form builder`, In one screen I want have small `container` with `icon` and text with `gesture detector`, when I tap on the `container` it should contruct a new `DatePicker` Widget. I know how to do it in the same screen, but `onTap` I want construct the `Datepicker` in another screen.
This is `Form Component` Class.

```
class FormComponents extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FormComponentsState createState() => _FormComponentsState();
}

class _FormComponentsState extends State<FormComponents> {
  final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> _fbKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();
  int _count = 0;
  final formData = FormWidgetData(widget: DatePicker());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> datePicker = List.generate(_count, (index) => DatePicker());

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Form Components'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FormBuilder(
              key: _fbKey,
              initialValue: {
                'date': DateTime.now(),
                'accept_terms': false,
              },
              autovalidate: true,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Builder(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _count = _count + 1;
                          });

                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            SnackBar(
                              content: Text('Date Picker'),
                              duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          height: 100.0,
                          width: 120.0,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(
                                Icons.date_range,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Date Picker',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 200.0,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Expanded(
                      child: ListView(
                        children: datePicker,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my Date Picker Class

```
class DatePicker extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FormBuilderDateTimePicker(
        attribute: 'date',
        inputType: InputType.date,
        format: DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'),
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'AppointmentTime'),
      ),
    );
  }  
}
```

This is my `Form Builder` Class, How to do I Construct the above `Date Picker` class here.

```
class MyFormBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  final FormWidgetData data;
  MyFormBuilder({this.data});

  @override
  _MyFormBuilderState createState() => _MyFormBuilderState();
}

class _MyFormBuilderState extends State<MyFormBuilder> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Form Builder'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 300.0,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check examples from [Navigation section](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data) in flutter docs, they demonstrate a similar but simplified use-case.

Comment: @dev-aentgs I saw the documentation, it pretty straight forward, I know how to do that, but still in my use case I am missing something out, I still cannot get it to work.

Comment: ok. Are the above `classes` in the same dart file or separated? if they are in separate dart files, `import` the dart files for formcomponents and datepicker  in formbuilder file. Then like inbuilt widgets you can directly call the `FormComponents()` and `DatePicker()`